# Grails export plugin Throws an Error "No Signature Of Method is allowed"

Tags: grails, plugins

Hi i am using grails export plugin and added the plugin in dependencies and mime type for excel.

I am passing the data in the below format:

```
 FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:/dummy/test1.xlsx")
 def empDate = [[joindate:2018-01-30,desig:Instructor]]
 List fields = ["joindate", "desig"]
 Map labels = ["joindate": "Join Date", "desig": "Designation"]

 exportService.export("xlsx", output,empDate, fields, labels, [:], [:])

 //Throws an error "No Signature of method is allowed for argument types ....."
```

Full error is

> No signature of method: com.test.ExportService.export() is appl icable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.io.FileOutputStream, java.util.ArrayLis t, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.Linked HashMap) values: [xlsx, java.io.FileOutputStream@10234, [[joindate:2018-01-30, ...]], . ..] Possible solutions: every()

Comment: A few clarifications: What version of grails?  What version of export plugin?  And can you add the full error given?

Comment: @Daniel - Grails 3.1 export plugin:2.0.0 and the error is "No signature of method: com.test.ExportService.export() is appl
icable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.io.FileOutputStream, java.util.ArrayLis
t, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.Linked
HashMap) values: [xlsx, java.io.FileOutputStream@10234, [[joindate:2018-01-30, ...]], .
..]  Possible solutions: every().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.test.ExportService.export()` indicates that you are using an export service implementation other than the one provided by the plugin.  You probably have a locally defined `ExportService` class that you are using accidentally.  Either rename your local class (preferred) or strongly type the injection to the one provided by the plugin.

Comment: @ Daniel I am using the exportService injection as below def exportService in my controller.Previously i created the ExportService but i deleted it later.But i wonder why it is still pointing to deleted service?

Comment: Try cleaning your project; the compiled class may still be there.

Comment: Any suggestions how to create different sheets in the same worksheet?